# IF cell is green add date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking to have a cell `M4` populate when I change either `J4`, `K4` or `L4` to a green fill.

For example: If I put the date `12-14` in `K4` and change the background fill to Green, I want `M4` to populate with the date `12-14`.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mount Indie, welcome. I believe what you're looking for is called conditional formatting, have you looked into that? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f You may want to retake the screenshot and include the row/column labels

Comment: Hello - Thank you! I was not sure conditional formatting would populate another cell based off of the color of a different cell. I thought conditional formatting worked differently, but I will continuing reading through the support articles... thank you

Comment: @wysiwyg Conditional formatting does the opposite of what Mount Indie wants to do.

Comment: If you are manually changing the cell green to indicate something, and NOT changing it to green based on a value in the spreadsheet, Auto populating the contact date will require VBA.  If there is something about the value of the cell of somewhere else in the sheet that cause the cell to be green than that can be done through conditional formatting, and the same criteria check used for conditional formatting can be used to auto populate your other cell.

Comment: Formulas cannot detect colours of cells, but VBA can

Comment: @ForwardEd thank you.... that is what I need to do... So looks like VBA is the answer or find a different way to do this. Thanks

Comment: You could add a helper column beside each of your call dates.  In this column you can add a letter to indicate the success of the call.  You can then use condition formatting to color the date based on the value in the adjacent column.  You can then also auto populate the the cell you want based on the value in the helper column being the condition check.

Comment: Your example shows different dates in multiple green cells.  The description is that a date in one of the green cells is supposed to show up in another cell (there are no row or column labels in the example).  You don't describe how to handle the situation in your example where a date must be selected from multiple values.  This requirement is like the chameleon that exploded trying to hide in a box of crayons.  BTW, will any colored cell always be green?  You can't test for green in a formula, but you can test whether the cell is colored.  Please clarify these issues by editing the question.

Comment: @fixer1234 sorry new hear i am editing the question and thanks

Comment: 1. Will the cell be either colored or not colored, and the color will always be green, or could there be green plus other colors (can we test for colored, or do we need to test for green)?  2. At most one of the columns will be green?  3. A green cell will always have a date?  4. If multiple cells in a row (J:L) have a date, will the dates always all be the same, as in the example, or can there be different dates on the same row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve your problem, I would like to suggest a few macros.**

**Macro 1:**

```vbs
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Set w = ActiveSheet.Range("J4:L4")

 For Each C In w

 If C.Value <> "" And Not IsDate(C) Then
 C.ClearContents

 MsgBox "Only a Date is permitted in this cell."
 End If

 If C.Value = "" And Not IsDate(C) Then
 C.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
 Else
 C.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
 End If

 Next C

End Sub
```

**Macro 2:**

```vbs
Sub CopyLastCell()
Range("J4").End(xlToRight).Copy
Range("M4").PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

**How the Macro works:**

- At the Active Sheet press `ALT+F11` to open `VBA Editor`.
- **Copy & Paste** both Macro as Standard Module.
- The **1st Macro** will only allow to enter `DATE` in Cells `J4:L4` and highlight cell/cells in Green Color, if finds `DATE` value.
- **RUN** the **Macro 2** when you want to **Copy** the Last Cell's value from `J4:L4` to Cell `M4`.

**N.B.**

- I've used the **LAST Cell Method** to **Copy** to `M4` *because it's very much possible that you may enter DATE in all cells or in few.*
- Data Range `J4:L4`, destination Cell `M4` & `Color Index` values are editable.

Comment: Glad to help you @Mount Indie keep asking ☺